# C convert struct dirent * to FILE *

Tags: c, file-io, filesystems, dirent.h

I'm writing a file browser in C that uses the equivalent of ls and cd to let the user navigate the filesystem and select a file. It's all working well - I can get as far as the user selecting a `struct dirent *` that represents the directory entry of the file they want to choose. However, I want to open this file in my program, and the only way I know how to do that is through `fopen(FILE* fptr)`. Is there a way I can convert a `struct dirent *` to a `FILE*`? A `struct dirent` has a property `ino_t d_fileno` which refers to "the file serial number" - is that the same as a file descriptor? Could I use that file descriptor to open a `FILE*`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't 'convert' a `struct dirent *` to `FILE *` because the first is just related to one directory entry no matter if it's a file, a sub directory or something else, no matter whether you have access rights to the file and so on while you can only have a `FILE *` for a file you have opened. Also. there's no way to open a file by it's inode,

What you **can** do, is building the file's pathname from the directory's name as you have used in `opendir()` and `dir->d_name` and `fopen()` that pathname:

```
 FILE *openfile( const char *dirname, struct dirent *dir, const char *mode )
 {
       char pathname[1024];   /* should alwys be big enough */
       FILE *fp;

       sprintf( pathname, "%s/%s", dirname, dir->d_name );
       fp = fopen( pathname, mode );
       return fp;
 }
```

Please note that I assume that, if `dirname` is not an absolute path, you don't do any `chdir()`s between calling `opendir( dirname )` and `openfile( .... )`

Answer (score -1):

You should not convert a `struct dirent *` to a `FILE *`. If you want the file name corresponding to a `struct dirent`, you can get it from this structure.

For example, if you have

```
struct dirent *dp = readdir(DIR directory);
```

then the file name of this directory entry is `dp->d_name`.

See [`readdir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) for further details.

Comment: Do you mean dp->d_name?